# CarbonInterval, undefined variable $slots

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="starttime"> Start time </label>
    <input type="time" name="starttime" class="form-control" id="starttime" value="12:00">

    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong></strong>
    </span>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="endtime"> end time </label>
    <input type="time" name="endtime" class="form-control" id="endtime" value="05:00">

    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong></strong>
    </span>

</div>
```

```php
public function storetimeintervals(SlotStoreRequest $request){

    $starttime = $request->starttime;
    $interval = $request->interval;
    $endtime = $request->endtime;
    
    $intervals = CarbonPeriod::since($starttime)->minutes($interval)->until($endtime)->toArray();
    foreach($intervals as $slot){

        $slots= Slot::create([
        
            'nslot'=> $slot->format('H:i'),
            
        
        ]);

    }
    if(!$slots){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error','Sorry, there a problem happened while creating slot'); 
    }
    return redirect()->route('slots.index')->with('success','The slots have been created');

}
```

I am using carbon interval to get timeslot between two time it works fine, but when I input start time in PM then the end time in AM it cause $slots undefined. Other than that it work without error

I am expecting to input between two time without error.

Comment: Can you share your request param values?

Comment: its 12:00PM to 05.00AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below payload

```
{
    "starttime" : "12:00PM",
    "endtime" : "05:00AM",
    "interval": 5    
}
```

I found this working .
Better you convert your requested time in the proper format first.

```
if(strtotime($request->endtime) < strtotime($request->starttime)){
        $starttime = Carbon::parse($request->starttime)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $endtime = Carbon::parse($request->endtime)->addDay(1)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
} else {
        $starttime = Carbon::parse($request->starttime)->format("H:i:s");
        $endtime = Carbon::parse($request->endtime)->format("H:i:s");
}
$interval = $request->interval;

$intervals = CarbonPeriod::since($starttime)->minutes($interval)->until($endtime)->toArray();
    foreach($intervals as $slot){

        $slots= Slot::create([            
            'nslot'=> $slot->format('H:i')
        ]);

    }
```

OR Check this fiddle

https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/23bd3a21-de15-45b0-9085-65a93c841d58

Comment: Thanks, but it still give the same erorr

Comment: Your error is on the line
` if(!$slots){`  so  it seem like your intervals were not created .

Comment: yeah if the start time is AM and the end time either AM or PM it works. But if start time is PM and the end time is AM is doesn't work. Its like you get negative number if a smaller number minus by bigger number and bigger number minus smaller number get positive. In this context  if you get negative number the $slot is not created

Comment: In that case you will require to pass the data too.. or put some logic like if the end time is less than the start time it will add a one data in current time and then display the time slot 
Let me help with

Comment: @MuhamadArif , I have edited my answer and fiddle too, Kindly check and let me know if that helps

Comment: Also the problem also occur the time is at PM and the end time 1200AM the $slot will not created because 12.00AM is 0000 in 24h format

Comment: You won't get any error. Just try with the above code..